# Can an Indian travel from Australia to Delhi with only 40 days of validity remaining on the passport?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, australia, air-india

Will I be able to take a non stop flight from Melbourne to Delhi with this validity?

I wasn't aware of the six month validity rule that exists in several countries. It never came up and I feel stupid for not having applied for a renewal.

Comment: Are you talking about entering India or re-entering Australia?

Comment: Entering India. I may have to stay a bit longer in India which will give me time to renew the passport. That's if I can make the journey.

Comment: @ReddHerring Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

The six-month rule is so that you're not left without a valid passport if you have to spend longer than expected abroad, e.g., because of a medical emergency. But, as an Indian citizen, you don't need to have a passport to be in India, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks! Is the rule only in place for the destinations and transit locations? Does Australia have any exit requirements on passport validity of foreign (Indian, in this case) citizens?

Comment: @user99801 Why would they have validity requirements on exiting people? They want visitors to leave: they're not going to make that difficult. If you want to know about transit locations, ask a specific question about that country as a new question.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if that sound stupid. I am relatively new to international travel. No, I won't be transiting. But that was very helpful.